# Is SQLite a good solution to backup postgres on Heroku?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, backup

I'm using the Sequel (Taps) ruby gem for a remote backup of my production database (PostgreSQL).

I wonder if storing that backup with SQLite is a good solution.

What's your feeling ?

Thx !

---

Edit:

Thanks! In fact, my app is hoted on Heroku and I though it was simply impossible to run pg_dump.

But -- I found that nice rake task : http://github.com/jpearl/heroku_backups

Comment: why do you not use PostgreSQL itself to store the backup? I believe it is less error-prone; or you can store directly the dump of your prod db as it is, without "replicating" the data in another db. But if you prefer this way, let the other db be PostgreSQL too.

Comment: heroku_backups is no more :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have much experience with Postgres and SQLite, but I do not feel comfortable with the type conversion that has to occur between the databases (you have to rely on both the PostgreSQL and the SQLite drivers for Ruby), nor with the synchronization problems that could arise if your production database is thoroughly used.

Have you already tried to restore the original database from the SQLite copy? What happens if the Sequel ruby gem is not maintained anymore?

The PostgreSQL manual has a [section dedicated to backup](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/backup.html) - The `pg_dump` command may be a good fit for your problem, and would have the advantage of maximal reliability.

Comment: I agree with jhominal, if you are going to backup, dump the database to a text file or something like that, very readable. If you are going to replicate, use exactly the same software.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is not a good solution for this. It does not have good compatibility with PostgreSQL. Instead of rolling your own, why not use the free Heroku PGBackups addon? It will take care of everything for you.

See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups